# 1 and 2 keys to change tabs in Safari (like in Opera)

Tags: safari, keybindings, opera, shortcut

In Opera browser 1 and 2 keys can be used to change between tabs. Is it possible to set up this shortcut in Safari? I tried adding a "Show Previous Tab" shortcut in keyboard preferences but is does not allow me to set a shortcut without a modifier key (ctrl/alt/cmd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts to switch between tabs in Safari are <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>{</kbd> (previous tab) and <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>}</kbd> (next tab).

You can also use <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, etc. to jump to the tab that corresponds with that number, up to 8 (e.g. <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> will jump to the fifth tab from the left, from whichever tab you're currently on). <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> will jump to the right-most tab.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't make the shortcut from keyboard preferences. I believe that you would add this shortcut from Automator however I am not on my computer right now so I think that will work but I haven't tested this specific shortcut. If that dosent work then there is always the option of "⌘+`/⌘+Shift+' " to go to the next or previous tab. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're asking, but I found SafariTabSwitching extension recently and am very happy with it
https://github.com/rs/SafariTabSwitching

It let's you switch tabs using Cmd-(tab number) like all other browsers.

Comment: This is part of Safari without the need for the extension, but also the extension doesn't precisely replicate the needs of the question which is that one can switch through all tabs using those two keys rather than switching to exactly tab 1 or 2.